# Can i do like this , Scrollview with in scrollview?

Tags: android, react-native, nested, scrollview, scrollable

In whole scrollview small scrollview can't work

```
 <Scrollview>
   <View>
{this.state.viewSection ? 
    <Scrollview>
     <View>
         <Text>
            //this portion i cant scroll 
         <Text>
    </View>
   </Scrollview> 
: null }
 </View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({viewSection : true})}></TouchableOpacity>
</Scrollview>
```

Main screen is in scrollview  after button press small view open but i need scrollview in small view . but i can't scroll small view

Comment: Use NestedScrollView as the parent

Comment: In the parent  Scrollview or child scrollview ????

Answer (score 0):

Add "**nestedScrollEnabled={true}**" property to the internal ScrollView and it will work as expected.

```
<NestedScrollView>
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  </ScrollView>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I try but its not working in my situation

Comment: @krunalraval try now. With NestedScrollView as parent